# Retrieve Toast Message height

Tags: sapui5

Working on a web application, I need to show one or multiple warning messages retrieved from a WS.

With this purpose I am using `sap.m.ToastMessage.show` and its offset property, so in case of multiple messages I could show them one on top of another.

Following code is actually working for me:

```
    showToastMessages: function(warnings){
        var msgList = warnings.split("|");

        for(var i = 0 ; i < msgList.length; i++){
            var xset = 0 ;
            var yset = -50 + (i * -70);
            sap.m.MessageToast.show(msgList[i],{
                offset: xset.toString() + " " + yset.toString()
            });
        }
    }
```

However I would like to retrieve height from message before, so I could iterate somehow like this:

```
    showToastMessages: function(warnings){
        var msgList = warnings.split("|");
        var msgHeight = 0;

        for(var i = 0 ; i < msgList.length; i++){

            var xset = 0 ;
            var yset = -50 - msgHeight;

            sap.m.MessageToast.show(msgList[i],{
                offset: xset.toString() + " " + yset.toString()
            });
            msgHeight = msgHeight + retrieveMsgToastHeight() + MSG_OFFSET;
        }
    }
```

So I could be sure, there is no overlapping between different messages using `msgHeight` variable.

**EDITED**

As proposed by Sunil, I modified my function as following:

```
    showToastMessages: function(warnings){
        var msgList = warnings.split("|");

        // CONSTANTS
        var PADDING = 25;// 45;     // Padding height of each message
        var CHAR_PER_LINE = 28;     // Aprox. number of characters per line in a toast message
        var HEIGHT_PER_LINE = 20;   // Height in pixels that is each line
        var MSG_OFFSET = 52;        // Vertical offset in order to avoid bottom margin
        var BTW_MSG_OFFSET = 5;     // Separation between messages

        var msgHeight = MSG_OFFSET;

        for(var i = 0 ; i < msgList.length; i++){
            var xset = 0 ;
            var yset = - msgHeight;

            var msgLen = msgList[i].length;
            if(msgLen !== 0){

                var linesNumber = Math.trunc(msgLen/CHAR_PER_LINE) + 1;

                sap.m.MessageToast.show(msgList[i],{
                    offset: xset.toString() + " " + yset.toString()
                });

                msgHeight = msgHeight + linesNumber*HEIGHT_PER_LINE + PADDING + BTW_MSG_OFFSET;
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Your offset should be based on the **length of the message** and **width of the [Message Toast](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.MessageToast.html)**. Since Width is fixed. You can figure out how much each line takes(approx. 25-30 Chars for default **width** of `15em`)

Also consider the `padding` involved.(would be constant)

Only variable here is your length of the previous message by which you can decide the `offset` property.

Comment: Thanks Sunil, I just modified my function as **edited**  in my message. Thought is no better solution so I have to use constans.